# CSV will not write in to matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

```
    %% Input Variables

nsbj=6;                                                                    %%define number of subjects
fps=0.001;                                                                 %%defining frames per second per frame rate
g=-9.81;                                                                   %%acceleration due to gravity

BW= 0;                                                                     %%Subject body weight measurement
SJW= 1;                                                                    %%Squat jump without arm movement = Jumptype 1
CMW= 2;                                                                    %%Countermovement jump without arm movement = Jumptype 2
SJ= 3;                                                                     %%Squatjump with arm movement = Jumptype 3
CM= 4;                                                                     %%Countermovement jump with arm movement = Jumptype 4
BAD= 5;                                                                    %%Bad trial, exclude this
JT_S_TN=xlsread('Group D_File Info.xlsx','Sheet1','A1:C82');               %%reading in the Jump type(JT), Subject(S) and Trial number(TN) for later use
%JT_S_TN=[JT_S_TN(:,2),JT_S_TN(:,3)];

%% Main loop: 1.0 Read in excel data in CSV format
    data = dir('C:\Users\Fliss\Documents\Uni Course\Year 2\Steph matlab\groupDmain\Trial*02d.CSV'); %% Counts the number of CSV files in the folder directory
    data1 = data(1:end,:);                                                 %%can delete trials that are not needed because they were bad/irrelevant
    njump=length(data1);                                                   %%number of jumps relate to the data1 size

for i = 1:njump;

      name1=[data1(i,:).('name')];
      m = ['C:\Users\Fliss\Documents\Uni Course\Year 2\Steph matlab\groupDmain\', name1];            % Finds the correct CSV file
      j = csvread(m,7000,5);                                                % Loads the CSV file into Matlab
end
```

it will not recognise the files to import them anyone know why? I have checked the files and know that I am referencing in the right file area.

Comment: Minor comments:  (1) Your title is misleading.  Do you mean that you can't **read** the values in?  (2) What is the exact error and where is this taking place in your code?  Please update your post so that we can see where the error is taking place

Comment: Is `'Group D_File Info.xlsx'` in the same folder as your MATLAB script?

Comment: @RobertP.: Wow... how could I have missed asking that!?